# PHP form is not submitting values to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

friends i need your help.. form validation is working fine... but the form is not submitting values to the database
here is the form

```
 <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="regForm">
    <input id="fname" placeholder="First name" type="text" name="fname" />
    <input id="lname" placeholder="Last name" type="text" name="lname" />
    <input id="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" name="email" />
    <input id="email" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="pass"/>
    <div id="email">Birthday<input id="dat" type="text" placeholder="DD" name="day" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return yr(event)"/>/<input id="dat" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" name="month" onkeypress="return yr(event)"/>/<input id="dat" maxlength="4" type="text" placeholder="YYYY" name="year" onkeypress="return yr(event)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input></div><div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input></div><div class="radiol"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="Others">Others</input></div>
    <input id="reg1" type="submit" value="Register" name="reg" />
    </form>
```

validation code in submit.php is working finebut the code for form submission is not working at all..
submit.php

```
<?php $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
  if(!$con)
  {
die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("test",$con);

  // declared variables
  $fn=$_POST['fname'];
  $ln=$_POST['lname'];
  $em=$_POST['email'];
  $pswd=$_POST['pass'];
  $date=new DateTime($_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day']);
  $sex=$_POST['sex'];

  // we check if everything is filled in

  if(empty($fn) || empty($ln) || empty($em) || empty($pswd))
  {
die(msg(0,"All the fields are required"));
  }

  // is the birthday selected?

 if (!@checkdate($_POST['month'],$_POST['day'],$_POST['year'])) {
 die(msg(0,"Please fill correct birthday"));
  }

 // is the sex selected?

 if(!$sex)
  {
die(msg(0,"Please select your gender"));
   }


  // is the email valid?

  if(!(preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/",    $_POST['email'])))
{die(msg(0,"You haven't provided a valid email"));}



    //Check whether Email already exists in the database
    $e_check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM registeration WHERE email='$em'");
    //Count the number of rows returned
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows($e_check);
    if($email_check > 0){die(msg(0,"This email is already used"));}
    // check the maximum length of password
    if (strlen($pswd)<5) {die(msg(0,"Please provide a longer password"));}
    //encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to database
    $pswd = md5($pswd);
    $qu = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registeration (id,fname,lname,email,password,birthday,sex,activated) VALUES ('','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$date','$sex','0')");
    if(!$qu) {
        die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
        }
        echo msg(1,"registered.html");

    function msg($status,$txt)
    {
return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
    }
   ?>
```

after successfull form submission user supposed to be redirected on registered.html but it is staying on the same page

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Please have a look at PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Is all the submitted values are getting on submit.php?

Comment: The `id` field in your insert is empty; is that correct?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Look in your server logs.

Comment: @Mostly Mostacho it is not submitting the form to the databse...

Comment: @Lan, id is primary key

Comment: @user2881430 error is only at query?

Comment: after successfull form submission user supposed to be redirected on registered.html but it is staying on the same page

Comment: Where is the line that check that the submit button was clicked for instance :  if (isset($_POST['submit']){ //Do something }

Comment: @StBlade
i tried that too...

Comment: @StBlade, well if that will be the matter than validation should be giving error, but it is working fine

Comment: You have checked that the page is being reached right? A simple echo at the top to confirm this.

Comment: @Mike W, I m even not getting any error...

Comment: I would suggest the same as @Ruddy.  Try putting echo statements at intervals in the code and see if the app progress to that.  Otherwise you will need a debugger in an IDE to try and see what the app is doing.

Comment: @Ruddy, yes it is, because validation is working perfectly...

Comment: So what's on the page when you click the submit button. Paste what it says.

Comment: the page is not going anywhere..

Comment: Meaning? submit.php isn't being run? You will have to start with the basics to find the problem as I cant see any with the code at the moment. Run through your code putting echo's at each part. Find how far its getting, make sure that SQL statement is being reached if so we can rewrite the statement and sort that.

Comment: Something is going wrong, and you will have an error message somewhere. Please post what you find in your server logs. If that reveals nothing add some echo statements so you can track how far you get in the code. Look at the responses from your server - a blank screen is typical of a 500 error on the server which usually means that your code has a syntax error. This is basic debugging stuff, and only you can do it.

Comment: what i discovered, variables are not getting value from $_POST[]

Comment: `$fn=$_POST["fname"];` Try that use `"` instead of `'`

Comment: still not working @Ruddy

Comment: Only just seen this because of that answer. You should be getting this error for the `$date` =  `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` You would be better off creating it as a string and storing it as a string in your database.

Comment: @Ruddy thanx it worked...
thank you friends...

Comment: No problem, gave me something to do at work. I was just showing you that your form would work as it is within this link [DEMO HERE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/yp1-0i4). :)

Comment: Why was this downvoted so many times?  I've put you back  up 1.  Although you used the words "not working" the problem seems to be clearly described.  It seems to lack what attempts you have made, but I dont feel it deserves downvoting.  I think you've become victim to the "its not working" fad of correcting some one's question when they say "its not working."  Although the problem seems to be clearly described any ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please write $date variable like this:

```
$date=$_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
```

and I am not able to see any code for redirection,so you can write below code

```
echo msg(1,"registered.html");
echo "<script>window.location='registered.html'</script>";
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Thanks

Comment: the code echo msg(1,"registered.html"); works if i remove the sql queries

Comment: date variable was the problem... thanx for your help... thanku alok